# Conway's Game Of Life

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life, cellular-automata

I am currently writting a programe about Conway's Game of life and I am really a beginner of python, I don't know how to start at all. Anybody can help me with it?

Comment: Would it not have been better to edit the offer out of the question rather than just close it. Essentially, it's a question about how to implement Life in Python.

Comment: Well I can't speak for everyone, but for myself I am always loath to edit anyone else's actual content. Typos, sure. Actual content not so much.

Comment: No, This isn't the kind of place where people should be offering to pay to have their homework done for them.  You learn by doing, not by paying someone to do your homework.

Comment: I guess, but there's so much missing from it - can they write software in other languages? Are they stuck on syntax? GUI? algorithms for running cellular automata?

Comment: In this case (if I could edit) I probably would have erred on the side of removing the offer rather than closing it out completely. IMO, it is an interesting question, just clumsily phrased :)

Comment: @kibbee... Well, I added the homework tag :) Seemed like an easy way to earn 50 quid though ;)

Comment: People can vote against closure with +1 for the question, normally if someone spots a closed question with +ve rep they'll reopen.

Comment: I reopened at 0.  I think it's a fine question, already answered, etc...  move on, nothing to see here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need to pay to learn python. Implementing cellular automata makes for good starting project.  The best place to start with python is the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) and you can follow that with [dive into python](http://www.diveintopython.org/).

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348506/starting-from-scratchi-need-some-direction) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348376/intro-book-on-cs-for-girlfriend) may be helpful as well.

If you can bear the self-praising and claims to godness [Wolfram's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1579550088) is a good way to get a feel for cellular automata, but don't take the book itself too seriously (that's a separate issue that can fill several blog posts). He also has a [set of papers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201626640) on this stuff that is published as a book that goes into all the details.  And of course if you just google for cellular automata and Conway's game you'll find a myriad of implementations and explanations.

Answer (score 4):

http://plife.sourceforge.net/

Send the 50 quid to me :)

(I'm kidding, of course)

Comment: Why kid?  I'll take the 50 quid for you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably get some good documentation here : http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085959/.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to post a [blog](http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/blog/Game_of_Life_in_XAML_WPF_using_embedded_Python) on implementing John Conway's Game of Life in XAML/WPF using embedded Python.  It might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

try here instead.

http://www.elance.com/p/landing/buyer.html

http://www.rentacoder.com/RentACoder/DotNet/default.aspx

These are places where you can hire people to do small freelance work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few people on the pygame.org website who've done their versions of the game of life. Maybe they'll be of help:
[Pygame.org - search "life"](http://www.pygame.org/tags/life)